# Jquery select2 синоним буквы ё

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

В селекте районы Москвы. Есть `Бирюлёво`.

Хотелось бы, чтобы когда пользователь писал `Бирюлево` срабатывал поиск и по букве `ё`.

Comment: ну документация говорит что эта опция по умолчанию включена https://select2.github.io/examples.html#diacritics _**Diacritics support** - Select2's default matcher will ignore diacritics, making it easier for users to filter results in international selects. Type "aero" into the select below._ Возможно вы уже сменили дефолтные настройки.

Comment: а вот нифига. поковырял исходный код. действительно есть поддержка, но только не для кириллицы. дописал туда свои пары `"ё":"е",` и все заработало.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете перезаписать функцию поиска своей

```
$('select').select2({
  matcher: function(term, text, option) {
    return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0 || /* сравнение с учетом буквы ё */
  }
});
```